# set object values from form

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have the following code that sets certain object(CarsCourse) values according to what the user selected in a web form.

The code works, but an associate of mine stated that this in the worst possible way of doing this.  However, he couldn't offer any suggestions.

So is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Thanks

```
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbDisplayName.Text) Then CarsCourse.DisplayName = tbDisplayName.Text
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbDescription.Text) Then CarsCourse.Description = tbDescription.Text
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbOfficialStartDate.Text) Then CarsCourse.OfficialStartDate = DateTime.Parse(tbOfficialStartDate.Text)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbOfficialEndDate.Text) Then CarsCourse.OfficialEndDate = DateTime.Parse(tbOfficialEndDate.Text)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbBtmDatepicker1.Text) Then CarsCourse.VisibleStartDate = DateTime.Parse(tbBtmDatepicker1.Text)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbBtmDatepicker2.Text) Then CarsCourse.VisibleEndDate = DateTime.Parse(tbBtmDatepicker2.Text)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlDepartment.SelectedValue) Then CarsCourse.SecondarySpecialtyName = ddlDepartment.SelectedValue
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlOptionType.SelectedValue) Then CarsCourse.OptionType = ddlOptionType.SelectedValue
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlOfficialName.SelectedValue) Then CarsCourse.OfficialCourseID = Guid.Parse((ddlOfficialName.SelectedValue))
```

Comment: I think what'd fit your needs was databindings and validation.  Validation would fail for values which are null or empty.

Comment: @ebeeb -I'm sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you are saying...

Comment: when is the above code executed? If you click on a OK button?

Comment: @ebeeb yeah, when I submit the form, that code is executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is not very well designed. The way of achieving this properly would be with *state* and *validation*.

So primary you have a form, which holds the current values of an object. I'd recommend to bind the corresponding object *directly* to the web form. Regardless of being null or empty the values are actually *set*.

As soon as the user presses the OK button, a `Save()` or `Validate()` method is executed on the corresponding object and the values are checked for their validity. *Cancel* the save process if validation fails and tell the user to update his input accordingly.

Comment: thanks, do you know of a good website that explains the above?

Comment: [Here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx) is a link that might get you started. I'm pretty unfamiliar with asp.net though.